# Guardar caracteres a un arreglo tipo String en Java

Tags: java, array

Intentando hacer un código en Java con caracteres y arreglos, intenté guardar un carácter en un arreglo tipo String y que cada vez se fueran añadiendo mas caracteres en el arreglo hasta acabar un ciclo.

**Ejemplo**

```
public void Numeros()
{
    String Arreglo[] = new String[5];
    int Contador = 0;
    while(Contador < 5)
    {
        int c =(int)(Math.random()*(122-97)+97);  //Crea letras aleatorias de la "a" a la "z" en la tabla ascii.
        char letra = (char)c;   //Transforma los enteros a caracter.
        Arreglo[0] = letra;
        Contador++;
    }
    System.out.println(Arreglo[0]);
}
```

**OBVIAMENTE EL ERROR ESTA AQUI**

```
while(Contador < 5)
{
    int c =(int)(Math.random()*(122-97)+97);   //Crea letras aleatorias de la "a" a la "z" en la tabla ascii.
    char letra = (char)c;   //Transforma los enteros a caracter.
    Arreglo[0] = letra;
    Contador++;
}
```

**Lo que quiero conseguir**

Cuando el contador en el cliclo while se termine, en el String Arreglo[0] (posición 0), tenga el conjunto de caracteres de todos los caracteres que se crearon aleatoriamente.

**Es decir (ejemplo)**

Que si las letras aleatoriamente creadas en la variable tipo char fueron "h", "o", "l", "a", que en el arreglo en la posición 0 (Arreglo[0]), contenga el String "hola".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución a lo que quieres conseguir sería algo como:

```
    String Arreglo[] = new String[5];
    Arreglo[0] = "";
    int Contador = 0;
    while (Contador < 5) {
        int c = (int) (Math.random() * (122 - 97) + 97);
        char letra = (char) c; // Transforma los enteros a caracter.
        Arreglo[0] = Arreglo[0] + letra;
        Contador++;
    }
    System.out.println(Arreglo[0]);
```

Te recomiento que escribas los nombres de las variables en minusculas (arreglo, contador).